# troubles with Biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using latex to write an essay, but I'm currently facing problems with my bibliography management (I'm using biblatex package with biber 1.8 as backend).
It seems that  the bbl file that gets generated sees '%' symbols in article abstracts as commenting commands, therefore jeopardizing the rest of the file.
Is there a way to tell biber not to import my article's abstracts or (even better) to tell him to substitute '%' with '/%? in abstract fields.
I read the guides provided but they're beyond my skill as IT.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can suppress abstract fields with a Sourcemap. But I have no idea if it works with biber 1.8 which is quite old (current ist 2.7).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!  You may also want to look at what makes a good Minimal Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a file `biber.conf` in the same folder containing your .tex file, in which you write the following:

```
<!-- biber ignores Abstract field  -->
<!-- No escape of special characters like % or & necessary -->
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_set="ABSTRACT" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Comment: @S.Neri You are welcome. Please consider marking the question as solved by clicking on the hook beside the answer.